# Anyone know the location of SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext() in windows?

Tags: winapi, windows-10

I need to turn off DPI scaling in my Win32 application. The recommended way to do this programmatically is via the call:

SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext()

I am using the mingw windows environment. I verified that mingw headers don't have the call, but then several newer calls are missing from the mingw headers. Its a lot of work to update those, I am sure.

I created a local definition of that:

```
#define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 3

extern BOOL SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(int value);

int main()

{

   SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2); 

}
```

I still get:

```
C:\projects\petit_ami>gcc -g3 -Iinclude -Ilibc -static tests/widget_test.c -Wl,--whole-archive bin/petit_ami_graph.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lcomdlg32 -lwsock32 -luser32 -o bin/widget_test
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: bin/petit_ami_graph.a(graphics.o): in function `pa_init_graph':
C:\projects\petit_ami/windows/graphics.c:15662: undefined reference to `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The best documentation I can find says it is in user32.dll.

This is using Windows 10 and recently updated, build: 19042.1052

Thanks for any help.
Scott Franco
San Jose, CA

Almost there. I did:

```
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PGNSI)(int);

    pGNSI = (PGNSI) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("user32.dll")),
                                   "SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext");
    if(NULL != pGNSI) {

dbg_printf(dlinfo, "Procedure found\n");
       r = pGNSI(2);
dbg_printf(dlinfo, "r: %d\n", r);
       if (!r) winerr();

    }
```

And got:

```
C:\projects\petit_ami>graphics_test
windows/graphics.c:pa_init_graph():15686: Procedure found
windows/graphics.c:pa_init_graph():15688: r: 0

Error: Graph: Windows error: The parameter is incorrect.
```

The description of the parameter is here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/dpi-awareness-context

I saw elsewhere that 2 was a valid value, but clearly that may not be correct. The suggestion by Simon to get the Visual studio environment may be operative just to get the proper value. Apologies to Simon, I can't at the moment take the rest of your suggestion. There is a long list of reasons I don't want to bore people with here.

Continued:

I installed and ran the visual studio with sample code. It works, now I am trying to figure out what DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 is, it is not a simple integer.

Anyways, its late. I try to find the final answer tomorrow.

Continued:

The working code is:

```
/* function call for direct to dll */
typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PGNSI)(int);

/* select for highest DPI */
#define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 0xfffffffc

...

    /* turn off scaling. The following call gets around the lack of a
       declaration in mingw */
    pGNSI = (PGNSI) GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("user32.dll")),
                                   "SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext");
    if (NULL != pGNSI) {

       r = pGNSI(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
       if (!r) winerr();

    }
```

As you could probably guess, I am going to tie this to a user option. Now I just need to research what the effect of this new mode is on widgets and other OS features.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: The definitive guide to where to locate it is at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setprocessdpiawarenesscontext. You need to include the appropriate `.lib` file in order to locate the function. Without seeing your code in the form of a [mre], it's impossible to explain the error you're getting.

Comment: If your compiler's copy of `user32.lib` doesn't expose the function, you can always use `GetProcAddress()` to access it directly from `user32.dll` at runtime.

Comment: Added the minimal example above. Note that it is just a linker "undefined reference" error. Thanks.

Comment: Remy, interesting. I guess before I do that I should dump the symbols list for user32.dll and verify that it actually exists. I was under the impression that gcc/mingw used the .dll directly, so you are saying it goes via a .lib file? Probably some of this comes from the fact I have never tried to access a call not in mingw's catalog of Windows calls. Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK gcc/mingw headers/lib are (often/always) out of date (not based on the Windows SDK). I would strongly recommend using Microsoft IDE/SDK/Compilers/Debuggers when seriously working on Windows.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the comment.

Comment: I found a tool on the nilsoft page that dumps dll exports, and was able to find the target SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext() symbol.

Comment: Yes, so my next step is I am installing visual studio. I have used it many times I actually used to work on MIcrosoft source code (the Windows operating system). I'll use that to  form a small test case for the SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext() call.

Comment: The argument is not an int, it's a handle (pointer size) and 2 is not valid. Use 0xFFFFFFFE in 32-bits or 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE in 64-bits. Like you say "get the Visual studio environment may be operative just to get the proper value". Using MinGW/GCC on Windows just cause waste of time on stupid problems :-)

Comment: You are correct, unfortunately I have to get this working with mingw first :-)

Comment: Why not through manifest?

Comment: DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 is (HANDLE)-4, so 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFC (64) or 0xFFFFFFFC (32)

Comment: So the first answer was provided by Remy, but all the above information was helpful. I didn't see a way to tag a comment as "the answer", so I tagged the answer below. Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Simon, yes, thanks, I got that number from VS as well. I could probably also pull the definition into my code, but hey, a kludge is a kludge.

Comment: @ScottFranco in your last edit, the correct declarations should look more like this instead: `DECLARE_HANDLE(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT); typedef BOOL (WINAPI *PGNSI)(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT); #define DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2 ((DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT)-4)`

Comment: "why not a manifest" The purpose of my PA project is to be portable across multiple operating systems. Code is portable. Odd associated data is not. In fact, PA is about 20 years old, and there were several very challenging problems in doing things only in the code. However, the results are good, and I am proud of the fact that I don't have to send my users looking for odd OS specific files to modify.

Comment: Hi Remy, yes, I was not sure mingw had the necessary declarations for that, but I tried it and it does work, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetProcAddress` works and is the recommended method when you cannot be certain if the user's OS will have the function.

If you want to resolve the symbol at link time, you need to ensure that (1) the import library has the symbol, and (2) that the calling convention and name decoration and mangling are correct.

I'm not very familiar with mingw, but I believe it comes with import libraries for some version of common Windows DLLs.  Since this is a newer function, it might not be in the import library.  There are tools to scan an existing DLL and create a corresponding import library, so perhaps you need to build a fresh one.

The calling convention for Win32 is `__stdcall`.  If your compiler is using a different calling convention by default, you'll have to set it explicitly on your forward declaration of the function.  Also, if you're compiling in C++ mode, you'll need to wrap the forward declaration in an `extern "C"` to prevent name mangling.  If either of these are wrong, you'll get an "undefined reference" diagnostic from the linker because the symbol will be "decorated" differently.